# What is this plant that I have growing in one of my pots?

Tags: identification

[image]
 I have never seen it before and it is really bugging me.

Answer (score 4):

It is Euphorbia lathyris, common name Caper Spurge. These pop up quite readily, usually from bird dropped seeds, and they are quite prolifically reproductive. Classed as a weed, and where there's one this year, there'll be several next year. If you remove it, wear gloves - the sap from this plant is a skin irritant.

Comment: Thank you bamboo. IO really appreciate the ID plus removal advice. Will follow.